# Excel add-ins in Python

Tags: python, excel, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins

Is there any way I can make **Excel** add-ins/extensions using Python?

I have tried javascript but haven't found any result about making add-ins on python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO (or OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for Python. There is no framework for Python developed by MS.

You may find custom extensions like [PyXLL](https://www.pyxll.com/) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could try xlOil (disclaimer: I wrote it).  The docs are [here](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xlOil_Python/index.html).  To write a simple three input function, you would install xlOil using:

```
pip install xloil
xloil install
```

Then write:

```
import xloil

@xloil.func
def myfunc(x, y, z):
    return x + y * z
```

Put this code either:

1. In a py file in the same directory as your spreadsheet, named `Book1.py` (if your sheet is called `Book1.xlsx`)
2. In a py file on your python module path, then edit `%APPDATA%\xlOil\xlOil.ini` to load it as described in the docs.

Start Excel, open your spreadsheet and the function will be available as `myfunc`.